How to deploy Django Webapp with subdomain
I have a domain as abc.com. I have created subdomain as xyz.abc.com.
I have two Django Webapps both are not same. I  want to deploy both Django Webapps with this domain and sub-domain on same VPS server.
Webapp deployed on main domain works very well. But when I try to do same thing with wepapp and sub-domain it shows error as Not Found.
I am using apache2 server to deploy webapp.
Here is my apache configuration.
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName xyz.abc.com
ServerAlias www.xyz.abc.com

DocumentRoot /home/altaf/LinkSuggestion/LinkSuggestion

Alias /static /home/altaf/LinkSuggestion/LinkSuggestion/static
    <Directory /home/altaf/LinkSuggestion/LinkSuggestion/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/altaf/LinkSuggestion/LinkSuggestion/LinkSuggestion>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess linksuggestion python-path=/home/altaf/LinkSuggestion/LinkSuggestion python-home=/home/altaf/LinkSuggestion/envlinksuggestion
    WSGIProcessGroup linksuggestion
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/altaf/LinkSuggestion/LinkSuggestion/LinkSuggestion/wsgi.py

   
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/linksuggestion_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/linksuggestion_access.log combined

   
</VirtualHost>

It shows error as :
**Not Found**
The requested resource was not found on this server.

